# How to do inference with YOLOv5 and ONNX

Tags: python, yolo, onnx, yolov5, onnxruntime

I've trained a YOLOv5 model and it works well on new images with yolo detect.py

I've exported the model to ONNX and now **i'm trying to load the ONNX model and do inference** on a new image. My code works but I don't get the correct bounding boxes.

I need to get the area of the bounding boxes etc. so **I can't just use detect.py**

Also I used Yolo's non_max_suppression to prune the list of bbox but I don't if it's a good solution.

What I did yet:

**# Load image and preprocessing**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
resized = cv2.resize(img, (640,640), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA).astype(np.float32)
resized = resized.transpose((2, 0, 1))
resized = np.expand_dims(resized, axis=0)  # Add batch dimension
```

**# run session on ONNX**

```
import onnxruntime as ort
ort_session = ort.InferenceSession("yolov5.onnx", providers=["CUDAExecutionProvider"])
# compute ONNX Runtime output prediction
ort_inputs = {ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name: resized}
ort_outs = ort_session.run(None, ort_inputs)
```

#### HERE I HAVE TENSOR WITH ALL THE BOUNDING BOXES

**# Keep only interesting bounding boxes**

```
import torch
from yolov5.utils.general import non_max_suppression, xyxy2xywh

output= torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(ort_outs))
out = non_max_suppression(output, conf_thres=0.2, iou_thres=0.5)[0]

# convert xyxy to xywh
xyxy = out[:,:4]
xywh = xyxy2xywh(xyxy)
out[:, :4] = xywh
```

**# Show bbox**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

tmp_image = Image.fromarray(img)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(tmp_image)

for i,(x,y,w,h,score,class_id) in enumerate(out):
  real_x = x * w_ratio # resize from model size to image size
  real_y = y * h_ratio

  shape = (real_x, real_y, (x + w) * w_ratio, (y + h) * h_ratio) # shape of the bounding box to draw

  class_id = round(float(class_id))
  
  class_string = list(class_list.keys())[list(class_list.values()).index(class_id)]
  color = CLASS_RECTANGLE_COLORS[class_string]

  draw.rectangle(shape, outline=color, width=4)
  fnt = ImageFont.load_default()

  draw.multiline_text((real_x + 8, real_y + 8), f"{class_string} {score*100:.2f}%", font=fnt, fill=color)

tmp_image.show()
```

Image with my algorithm vs detect.py :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxNLJ.jpg

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to give up and use this code :

```
import cv2
import torch
from PIL import Image

# Model
model = torch.hub.load(path_to_yolo_library, 'custom', path=onnx_path, source='local') 

img = Image.open(image_path)  # PIL image

img = img.resize((640,640))

# Inference
results = model(img, size=640)  # includes NMS

# Results
results.print()  # print results to screen
results.show()  # display results
results.save()  # save as results1.jpg, results2.jpg... etc.

# Data
print('\n', results.xyxy[0])  # print img1 predictions
```

Comment: so you are using only this code? roboflow_weight_path this is you yolo model weights ?

Comment: @JyotiPrajapati answer was not clear, I have edited with proper variable names. Yes path= is the path to the model weights

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried converting the image to RGB from BGR when reading it? As opencv loads image in BGR channel format by default, the unchanged flag might not be working as intended. As the model expects rgb images, the model is failing to detect anything.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. If I gave images loaded with cv2 to my model (BGR) will I still need to give RGB image to do the inference ?

Comment: Yes. The model is trained with rgb images, so if you give images in BGR format, the weights for these channels are incorrect thus producing poor result.

Answer (score 0):

just load image like this - `img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Why does loading the image in a slightly modified way solve the problem? Could you please [edit] your answer according to [answer] to explain why this does indeed fix the bounding boxes?